# What does "s-[keyname]" refer to in Emacs, and how do I tell Emacs to ignore it?

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp

Background information:

I'm on a Mac, and I've just upgraded to Emacs 23.1 via http://emacsformacosx.com/. There are a few issues, notably the lack of full screen ability.

I've attempted to get around this last issue by installing [Megazoomer](http://ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html), which adds a global input manager bound to `Cmd-return`. This causes the currently forward application to maximise. However, Emacs reports that `<s-return> is undefined`. I've never seen an `s-[key]` mentioned before, and Google isn't forthcoming with an answer.

So, two parts:

1. What does `s-[key]` mean? This is purely for my satisfaction; and
2. Can I tell Emacs to ignore this key combination and let the key combination carry through to the system (so that hopefully I can have full screen Emacs back again)?

EDIT: so 1) is resolved, and as to 2) I've got: `(global-set-key (kbd "<s-return>") 'ignore)`, which at least stops the error. However, Emacs still swallows the key combination, which isn't ideal.

Comment: If you're new to Mac, you might want to try Aquamacs. F7 (or m-X aquamacs-toggle-full-frame) toggles full-screen mode.

Comment: I'm not new to the Mac, I'm new to Emacs. And I've tried Aquamacs and didn't like it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So I've got:

(global-set-key (kbd "<s-return>") 'ignore)

which means I no longer get an error, but Emacs still swallows the combination. :(

Comment: You would normally bind a key to `nil` to remove that binding from the keymap in question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's the [Super key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html), like `M-` is the Meta key (alt key on a PC keyboard, Command key on your keyboard) and `C-` is the Control key.

I have of course never actually seen a super key on my keyboard... they are from a long gone era. Wikipedia has an image of this impressive ["Space Cadet keyboard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard) which has all the modifiers you'll ever need:

[image]

Comment: I would really love to have one of these nowadays. +1 for the pic.

Comment: Me too, imagine having a thumbs-up and thumbs-down button on your keyboard! Not to mention the four roman numerals... :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. You wouldn't happen to know how I can tell Emacs to drop that combination though...?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know the answer to your second part. I can only offer this link which has several recipes: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen

Comment: ... except that it says: "fullscreen functionality has not made it into Emacs-23 as of early 2009" when talking about full screen on Mac OS X :-(

Comment: I don't think Emacs is doing anything with that key combination.  If it gets to Emacs, it means your window manager doesn't think that key does anything.

Comment: To ward off some confusion between the key binding syntax in Emacs: The lower case "s" followed by a dash, `s-`, stands for the Super modifier, while upper-case "s", `S-`, stands for the Shift modifier (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-faq.html#Binding-combinations-of-modifiers-and-function-keys).

Comment: @BradWright `C-x @ s` applies the super modifier to the next key you press, i.e. `C-x @ s RET` would be equivalent to `s-RET`. But it's probably more convenient to just rebind the command you are interested in. Type `C-x @ C-h` for more info.

Answer (score 8):

With plain Emacs 23.1 on a Macbook Pro, I can map the right option key to `super` by

```
(setq ns-right-option-modifier 'super)
```

Your other choice seems to be the function key, which would be `ns-function-modifier`. However, *fn* might have other uses, whereas Emacs’ default is to map `ns-right-option-modifier` to `’left` (ie, the same effect as the left option key, which I at any rate need to get the `#` character!), so the right option key is to some extent redundant.

Left-handers may want to reverse this.

Answer (score 2):

For the question about what the s-[key] means, on ubuntu box it means the Windows® shaped key. What it means on the OSX systems, I do not know.

As for maximizing windows, could you try this?
(It should work, iif OSX runs an X server somewhere underneath it all)

```
(if (equal (window-system) 'x)
  (progn
   (defun toggle-fullscreen ()
     "Toggles fullscreen"
     (interactive)
     (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
              '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0))
     (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
              '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0))) 

   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-y") 'x-clipboard-yank)
   (global-set-key (kbd "M-RET") 'toggle-fullscreen)))
```

This little snippet is what I use to toggle fullscreen on my *nix computers. And yanking from X's clipboard is a neat ability to have.

As for how to set keybindings, use global-set-key for mode independent keybindings.
(Add it to your .emacs file if you want it to be permanent.)

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq ns-command-modifier nil)
```

That is supposed to do what you want.  However, it's having somewhat unpredictable behaviour on machine when I test it, so be warned.