# Emacs revert-buff (s-u): what is s-u?

Tags: emacs

The emacs help page for the M-x revert-buffer command says that it is bound to "s-u". What the heck is s-u? I know M-x is Meta-x (usually alt-x), and I know that C-x is Control-x. But what is s-u?

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) with Emacs: 23.3.1, s-u corresponds to Cmd-u.

Answer (score 3):

The "s-" modifier is the "super" key, which on a standard PC keyboard is the window key.

This makes such shortcuts unusable on Windows AFAIK, but I have a few bound on my Linux.

I don't know what key this corresponds to on an Apple keyboard though.

Answer (score 2):

- [What does "s-[keyname]" refer to in Emacs, and how do I tell Emacs to ignore it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354469/what-does-s-keyname-refer-to-in-emacs-and-how-do-i-tell-emacs-to-ignore-it/1354474#1354474)
- https://superuser.com/questions/204946/what-is-emacs-keybinding-s-u

Summary: It's your "Super" key.

(Emacs is nothing if not consistent with their naming - apparently it's *usually* Meta)

Comment: "(Emacs is nothing if not consistent with their naming - apparently it's usually Meta)" - wtf? so strange...so true. so sad :(